# how follow the instantiated object to other instantiated object

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

i want to follow the instantiated ball to my instantiated player. when my ball follow the player from hierarchy it work fine but when i instantiate the player it does not work .

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ExtraBallController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    private int distance = 30;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        this.transform.position = new Vector3 (target.transform.position.x, target.transform.position.y, distance);
    }
}
```

Comment: try declaring target as GameObject.

Comment: What "does not work". Have you any error? If the player is instantiated at run time, you may need to retrieve your target at run time too. There are numerous possibilities. The easiest (and dirtiest) one is to call (once) `GameObject.Find`. Since you haven't provided the code you use to instantiate your player, it's hard to give you a precise solution.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @Hellium i did not get any error but the ball is not following the player

Answer (score 0):

As @Hellium said, there are numerous possibilities. One way is to set the balls' target when the player is instantiated.
Here's a sample code (Not Tested):

```
GameObject player = Instantiate(playerPrefab, vectorPos, Quaternion.Identity);
ExtraBallController[] balls = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(ExtraBallController)) as ExtraBallController[];
foreach(ExtraBallController ball in balls){
ball.target = player.transform;
}
```

Hope this helps!